# Exception to raise when implementing a python deleter

Tags: python, exception

I am implementing a class in which I want an attribute to never be deleted i.e. `del myClass.immortal_attr`. What Exception is acceptable to raise for when the user attempts to do this?

None of the builtin exceptions seemed obvious to me, it doesn't feel like I should need to implement a custom Exception class. Something like `DeleteError` seems like a fairly universal need.

Comment: Why not an `AttributeError`?

Comment: Or simply `RuntimeError`.

Comment: `RuntimeError` would be my choice if nothing else is appropriate, which is what I wasn't sure of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raise an `AttributeError`, just like the types that come with Python do:

```
>>> del (1).bit_length
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'int' object attribute 'bit_length' is read-only
>>> class Foo(object):
...     @property
...     def x(self):
...         return 3
...
>>> del Foo().x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't delete attribute
```

Incidentally, implementing your attribute with a `property` might be a good way to achieve what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `AttributeError` might work for what you are trying to do, but you could also create your own custom exception if that doesn't quite suit what you want to do.

This site might be able to help you figure out how to create a custom exception. https://www.codementor.io/python/tutorial/how-to-write-python-custom-exceptions

Comment: Is deletion with `del` an [attribute reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#AttributeError)?

Comment: Hmm. I'm honestly not positive. Are you using `(object).__del__(self)`? Looking at the documentation for that, it looks like exceptions for this are totally ignored. [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__)

Comment: @Colby: `del` and `__del__` are unrelated.

Comment: @user2357112: Not always true. `__del__` (`del var`) and `__delattr__`/`__delete__` (`del var.attr`) are different things though